# Angular pass data from a component to another widget component

Tags: angular

I have my main component which is responsible for interoperating a service to recover data.
On my basic template, I use a component widget which brings up a list.
I would like to be able to retrieve the data from the main component to display them in the template of my widget (so that it is displayed at the end in my base template)

Here is the line in question on my basic template:

```
<vex-widget-tank-details gdColumn="1 / 3" gdColumn.lt-md="1 / -1" gdColumn.lt-sm="1"></vex-widget-tank-details>
```

Here is the component of my widget

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import icCheckCircle from '@iconify/icons-ic/twotone-check-circle';

@Component({
  selector: 'vex-widget-tank-details',
  templateUrl: './widget-tank-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-tank-details.component.scss']
})
export class WidgetTankDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  icCheckCircle = icCheckCircle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is the template of my widget

```
<div class="card bg-primary" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
  <div class="p-4 ml-4" fxFlex="none" fxFlexAlign="center">
    <img src="assets/img/illustrations/checklist.svg" style="height: 168px; width: 152px">
  </div>

  <div class="p-6 text-primary-contrast" fxFlex="auto">
    <h2 class="headline m-0"></h2>
    <p class="caption m-0 opacity-50">You've finished all of your tasks for this week.</p>

    <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <ic-icon [icon]="icCheckCircle" class="mr-2" size="24px"></ic-icon>
      <span class="body-2 cursor-pointer">Finish Dashboard Design</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-1" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <ic-icon [icon]="icCheckCircle" class="mr-2" size="24px"></ic-icon>
      <span class="body-2 cursor-pointer">Fix Issue #74</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-1" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <ic-icon [icon]="icCheckCircle" class="mr-2" size="24px"></ic-icon>
      <span class="body-2 cursor-pointer">Publish version 2.3.3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A big thank you in advance for your feedback